# String comparison to constant error

Tags: java, html, url, line, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I have this code its working fine in retreiving the value from the url, but its not recognizing that the string is "True" is the toString() what I need or something else?

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.koolflashgames.com/test.php?id=1");
    URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc
            .getInputStream()));
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    inputLine = inputLine.toString();
    if(inputLine == "True") {
        logger.info(inputLine);
        player.sendMessage("Thanks");
    }else{
        logger.info(inputLine);
        player.sendMessage("HAHAHA");
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use `equals` to compare strings, not `==` (reference equality).

Comment: we must make a different stackexchange site for string-compare-problems in java. All of their answers end up nearly being "use .equals"

Comment: @Aniket: That's what the "close as duplicate question" is for, isn't it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yet none of these questions get marked as duplicates

Comment: Since you are having only one line of text you won't need the toString() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `==` to compare the content of Strings, as they are objects. You have to create a method to compare objects. In the case of strings, you can use `stringName.equals(otherString)`.

Comment: Well you *can* use `==` on objects, but it means something else.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably edit that in.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my problem. Sorry if my question seemed so obvious, I've just started to work with java.

Comment: You're welcome. We all start somewhere :)

Answer (score 3):

You must use equals to compare strings. Replace:

```
if(inputLine == "True") {
```

with:

```
if(inputLine.equals("True")) {
```

The operator == tells you if two references refer to the same object, not if the values are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ. Use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` method to compare the string ignoring the case. This will match all cases, such as "True", "TRue", "tRue".. etc approximately 16 matches.

Comment: What if he does not want that functionality? But still, a helpful suggestion +1.

Comment: it will still match his string @eboix :-P

Comment: I like to use `.equalsWithTypos()` so it matches stuff like "treu" and "ture".

Comment: @PaulBellora I use `equalsWithSpeech` that matches phonetically similar sounding words.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compare `String` objects, use the `equals()` method.

The `==` operator checks whether the two `String`s have the same reference.

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more info.